# Proving an implication in a linear regression

Tags: probability, probability-theory, regression, regression-analysis

> Suppose we have a linear regression:  $$ y_i=X_i'\beta+u_i,\quad
> i=1,\ldots,T. $$ Here $y_i$ and $u_i$ are scalars, $X_i$ and $\beta$
>   $k\times 1$. $\beta$ is a (non-stochastic) vector of parameters. I'm given that $$ E[u_i|X_i]=0,\quad\forall i;\\
>  E[u_iu_j|X_i,X_j]=\sigma^2I[i=j] $$ with $I$ being the indicator
>   function. How do I show that $$
>  \text{Cov}(y_i,y_j|X_i,X_j)=\sigma^2I[i=j]? $$

**Attempt**: 
$$
\text{Cov}(y_i,y_j|X_i,X_j)=\text{Cov}(X_i'\beta+u_i,X_j'\beta+u_j|X_i,X_j)\\
=E(X_i'\beta X_j'\beta+X_i'\beta u_i+X_j'\beta u_j+u_iu_j|X_i,X_j)-E(X_i'\beta+u_i|X_i,X_j)E(X_j'\beta+u_j|X_i,X_j)
$$
which is simplified to
$$
E(u_iu_j|X_i,X_j)-E(u_i|X_i,X_j)E(u_j|X_i,X_j)
$$
so I will be done if I can show
$$
E(u_i|X_i,X_j)E(u_j|X_i,X_j)=0.
$$
But I can't proceed further.

Comment: Well, you can't proceed further because it's not true without stronger exogeneity assumption on the regressor.

Comment: @Michael Thanks. I'll check with the instructor.

Answer (score 0):

You are told that 
$E[u_i|X_i]=0 $ for all i.

By the law of iterated expectations, this implies that

$E[E[u_i|X_i]|X_j]=0$

but I'm fairly confident the term on the LHS is the same as $E[u_i|X_i,X_j]$ by the law of total probability...